# How to add row values based on specific column conditions?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe X with 20 different stocks, with observations of their respective daily returns for 10 years. The dataframe X looks as follows:

| Stock | Date | Return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BKR | 01.02.2002 | 2% |
| BKR | 02.02.2002 | -1% |
| BKR | 03.02.2002 | 1% |
| BKR | 04.02.2002 | 2.5% |
| BKR | 05.02.2002 | -3% |
| BKR | 01.03.2002 | 2% |
| BKR | 02.03.2002 | 1% |
| BKR | 03.03.2002 | -2% |

And I wish to transform these daily returns into quarterly returns, thus adding daily returns for a period of 3 months (as these are continuous returns, they are additive). The condition should be that the stock is the same (the example only shows BKR and USP but I have 20 different ones). In other words, I wish to have a dataframe Y looking like this:

| Stock | Quarter | Return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BKR | 01.2002 | 4% |
| BKR | 02.2002 | -15% |
| BKR | 03.2002 | 11% |
| BKR | 04.2002 | 2% |
| BKR | 01.2003 | -31% |
| BKR | 02.2003 | 21% |
| BKR | 03.2003 | 12% |
| BKR | 04.2003 | -2% |
| USP | 01.2002 | 1% |
| USP | 02.2002 | -13% |
| USP | 03.2002 | 12% |
| USP | 04.2002 | 8% |
| USP | 01.2003 | -13% |
| USP | 02.2003 | 2% |
| USP | 03.2003 | 14% |
| USP | 04.2003 | -3% |

Comment: Are you sure these percentages are additive? Consider stock X; starts at 100USD. Day 1 it gains 10%, now at 110USD. Day 2 it loses 10%, now it's at 99USD. This is not 0%, as a simple addition of the percentages would suggest. Correct me if I'm wrong or misunderstood your question.

Comment: As I computed continuous returns by using ln(y/y-1), returns are additive. You can try to perform the operation with the numbers you provided: ln(110/100) + ln(99/110) = ln(99/100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following solution using `lubridate` and `dplyr`:

```
#make a sample dataframe
x <- data.frame(Stock = c(rep('BKR',12), rep('TMP',12)),
                Date = c('01.01.2002','01.02.2002','01.03.2002','01.04.2002','01.05.2002','01.06.2002','01.07.2002','01.08.2002','01.09.2002','01.10.2002','01.11.2002','01.12.2002','01.01.2003','01.02.2003','01.03.2003','01.04.2003','01.05.2003','01.06.2003','01.07.2003','01.08.2003','01.09.2003','01.10.2003','01.11.2003','01.12.2003'),
                Return = c("2%","-4%","6%","1.2%","-1%","-1%","1%","2%","3%","8%","-3%","2%","12%","-8%","7%","13%","-24%","-1%","5%","6%","3%","2%","-3%","8%"))
x$Return <-  as.numeric(sub("%", "", x$Return, fixed=TRUE))/100
x$Date <- as.Date(x$Date, format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

```
#summarise the data
result <- x %>%
  group_by(quarter(Date, with_year = T), Stock) %>%
  summarize(year = year(Date), 
            quarter = quarter(Date),
            additive_return = sum(Return), 
            .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  select(-`quarter(Date, with_year = T)`) %>% 
  mutate(additive_return = paste0(formatC(additive_return * 100, format = "f", digits = 2, ), "%"))
```

You will get the following output:

```
> result
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  Stock  year quarter additive_return
  <chr> <dbl>   <int> <chr>          
1 BKR    2002       1 4.00%          
2 BKR    2002       2 -0.80%         
3 BKR    2002       3 6.00%          
4 BKR    2002       4 7.00%          
5 TMP    2003       1 11.00%         
6 TMP    2003       2 -12.00%        
7 TMP    2003       3 14.00%         
8 TMP    2003       4 7.00%
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, you can first `mutate` the dates so that they are distinguished only by year and month, then `group_by` `Stock` and `Date`, to finally calculate the summed `Return`s for the groups :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Date = sub("(\\d{4})-(\\d{2}).*", "\\2.\\1", Date)) %>%
  group_by(Stock, Date) %>%
  summarise(Return = sum(as.numeric(sub("%", "", Return))))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Stock [2]
  Stock Date    Return
  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
1 A     01.2000    6.5
2 B     02.2000    2.3
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Stock = c(rep("A",3), rep("B",3)),
  Date = c(seq(as.Date("2000-1-1"), as.Date("2000-1-3"), "days"),
           seq(as.Date("2000-2-1"), as.Date("2000-2-3"), "days")),
  Return = c("4%", "-1%", "3.5", "2%", "4%", "-3.7%")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `Return` col to numeric first:

```r
df$Date = as.Date(df$Date, "%d.%m.%y")
df$Q = quarters(df$Date)
aggregate(Return~Stock + Q, df, sum)

Stock  Q     Return
BKR    Q1    2.5
```